# Which meanings of the words "excitation" and ''match'' fit in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Which meanings of the words "excitation" and ''match'' fit in this context?

> The resulting amplitude of oscillation of the system becomes large
> when the frequency of the driving force approaches the natural free
> oscillation frequency of the system. This **excitation** of large
> oscillations by **match**ing input and natural frequencies is called
> resonance.

I have checked all available dictionaries and found many meanings for the verb ''excite''. Here are some of the meanings that I think can apply here:

1-stir up, instigate, incite

2-To induce, provoke (actions, manifestations); to bring about, occasion (active conditions).

3-act as a stimulant

4-bring out or give rise to (a feeling or reaction): the ability to excite interest in others.

5-produce a state of increased energy or activity in (a physical or biological system): the energy of an electron is sufficient to excite the atom.

6-to cause; awaken: to excite interest or curiosity.

7-to cause or bring about; stir up: to excite a rebellion

Since English is not my native language, I cannot tell which of these meanings apply here.I use Google translator to write these sentences. I think "excite" here should mean, for example, to cause oscillation, etc. what you think about that? am I right?

For match, the meaning I found was this:
''To make equal'' but I'm not sure.

If you know the correct meaning for these words, please guide me

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? On this site, we expect people asking questions to do some basic work to find the answer on their own before asking here. If you did look them up, please edit your question to tell us what you found, what you think they mean, and what you're still unsure about. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The meaning of "excite" is sense 5 "produce a state of increased energy". The large oscillations are an excited state of the system with increased energy. In a simple mechanical system, you can excite it by pushing regularly at some frequency.

"Excite" is a technical term in the physics of resonant systems, and the dictionary may not fully capture all the senses when being used in this technical sense, but see similar uses in the [Wikipedia article on Mechanical Resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mechanical_resonance#Description)

Match does mean "make equal".